# angularjs accessing array object from directive

Tags: angularjs

i am simply trying to build a directive that can already access an existing array of json data. the table displays, but can someone tell me how i can get the data to still display in the table.not sure how to access it.

```js
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        myApp.controller('countryController', ['$scope',function($scope) {

                var countries = [{
                        "code": "AD",
                        "name": "Andorra",
                        "population": "84000"
                    }, {
                        "code": "AE",
                        "name": "United Arab Emirates",
                        "population": "4975593"
                    }, {
                        "code": "AF",
                        "name": "Afghanistan",
                        "population": "29121286"
                    }, {
                        "code": "AG",
                        "name": "Antigua and Barbuda",
                        "population": "86754"
                    }, {
                        "code": "AI",
                        "name": "Anguilla",
                        "population": "13254"
                    }, {
                        "code": "AL",
                        "name": "Albania",
                        "population": "2986952"
                    }






                ]
                $scope.countries = countries;
                console.log(countries);
            }
        ]);


        myApp.directive('countryLoop', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    code: '@',
                    name: '@',
                    population:'@'
                    //countries:'&'

                },
                template: '<table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10"><tr><td>Country</td><td>Code</td><td>Population</td></tr><tr ng-repeat="country in countries"><td>{{country.name}}</td><td>{{country.code}}</td><td>{{country.population}}</td></tr></table>',
                link: function($scope, element) {


                }
            };



        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-App="myApp">
<div ng-controller="countryController">
        <table border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <td>Country</td>
                <td>Code</td>
                <td>Population</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
                <td>{{country.name}}</td>
                <td>{{country.code}}</td>
                <td>{{country.population}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<br>
    <country-loop></country-loop>
    
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind it with parent:

```
scope: {
  code: '@',
  name: '@',
  population:'@'
  countries:'=' // which is equals to "countries:'=countries'"
}
```

and then when you are using your directive you need to specify collection field:

```
<country-loop countries="countries"></country-loop>
```

If you need to call directive attribute differently for some reason you also can specify the name of the attribute you are binding to:

```
countries:'=data'
```

will take the data from "data" attribute and assign it with "countries" field in your directive scope.

```
<country-loop data="countries"></country-loop>
```

Comment: do i still use restrict: 'E'

Comment: got it..it wasnt in the controller